# Defining the structure of hierarchical data versus actually storing the data

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to develop a survey application that can deal with various types of responses, such as boolean, multiple choice, as well as ranges from 1-5, 1-10, 1-100, -2 to +2, even decimal values.  So, I've created a hierarchy of Response types:

```
class Response {
        String name
}

class BooleanResponse extends Response {
        boolean score
}

class SimpleGradeResponse extends Response {
        char score // A-F
}

class ComplexGradeResponse extends Response {
        char score // A-F
        char modifier // +, -, blank
}

class IntegerResponse extends Response {
        int min, max, score
}

class DecimalResponse extends Response {
        double min, max, score
}
```

I think of that as the metadata.  It describes the survey response types.  You could have question 1 that's an IntegerResponse from 1 to 10, question 2 that's an IntegerResponse from 0-100, question 3 that's a DecimalResponse, etc.

Where I'm uncertain is where to store the actual responses from users.  Do you mingle the scores in with the metadata, as I've done with the score field above?  That seems awkward, since every range-type response carries with it the min and max.

What I really want (I think) is to be able to curry the range response parameters to create a new type, and then reflect that type in a table of actual responses.  So, a question that takes a 1-10 range would be a row in IntegerResponse with min=1 and max=10.  But how does the ActualResponse table (I need to improve the naming convention, once I figure this out!) hold a score and refer to the curried IntegerResponse with min and max set?

If there is a better way to approach this whole problem, I'm eager to hear it.

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: sounds to me like your problem is not grails or groovy related but more in the domain of is in the realm of domain modelling and object-oriented design...

Answer (score 0):

1. `min` and `max` should rather be stored in a `Question` object, or even in `QuestionType` - depending on how flexible the system should be in runtime.
2. Will there be arbitrary limitations to different kinds of `Response`s? Data structure hugely depends on it. You can either hardcode different `Response` types or support them in runtime. First approach is one order of magnitude simpler.

Comment: Thanks, Victor. I'm trying to make sense of your post, but I'm not sure I get it. What is the relationship of Question to Response? How do you enforce that a particular Response is of a certain Question type? Regarding your item 2, I think it will be okay to hardcode Response types, though I don't quite understand how that simplifies things. Isn't that just a matter of constant min/max, rather than member variables min/max? Or are you referring to something more sophisticated than my examples? I'm sorry to say you may have to spoon feed me on this one. :-) Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: Probably I have a very different survey structure in mind. Can you please give some samples of questions you're thinking about?